# Unexplainable 301 redirect persists after redirect is deleted

Tags: htaccess, redirects, wordpress, 301-redirect

I am using wordpress on a domain on my server and I am trying to configure redirects from a parked domain to my main domain.

My main domain uses wordpress. My parked domain uses nothing (no wordpress or anything, just an htaccess file). Both are hosted on the same server. After deleting the redirect from htaccess and cPanel, the redirect still occurs.

The problem I am having is that the redirect from my parked domain to my main domain continues to exist EVEN AFTER THE REDIRECT IS DELETED. Whenever I type in the home page URL for my parked domain, the browser redirects to the home page of my parked domain.

I suppose normally I would post my htaccess for both domains, but there's no point, I completely emptied the .htaccess files for both domains and this still continues to occur. There are also no redirects configured anywhere in my cPanel.

What would be causing this redirect to persist even after it is deleted?

Comment: Where did you have the domain parked?   Did you change the DNS for the parked domain to un-park it?  Where do the NS records point now?  Where do the `A` and `CNAME` records point now?

Comment: WordPress can sometimes issue redirects itself.  What are your site url and home URL set to [in your WordPress config](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)?

Comment: You're not getting my question, the redirect continues to exist after it was deleted, it doesn't exist anywhere, not in wordpress or cpanel, not in an htaccess file. I totally reset the server to its original state and yet I still see the redirect.

Comment: I'm guessing you didn't un-park your domain correctly and the parking service you used is still controlling it.   I can't verify that unless you provide the information I requested.

Comment: @sparaps Did you add the parked domain in cPanel using an Alias or Addon Domain? If you've removed it in the corresponding place that you added it, then it might be your browser that's cached the `301` redirect, which they tend to do. Try using a different browser or clearing its cache. You can also verify the redirect is occurring at the server level using an online redirect or HTTP header checker, or by viewing the server logs. Other things you can try are restarting Apache, restarting the server, and making sure there isn't a CDN in the mix (which can also cache redirects).